# Tunneling a mobile web server using a proxy server

Tags: mobile, proxy, gprs

I have a mobile webserver, which is connected to internet through GPRS. ISP only provide a private IP, so is not possible to access to it using something like no-ip or dyndns. Is there a way to use a proxy server to access to this mobile webserver?:

1. Mobile webserver stablish connection with proxy server
2. a web browser (client) stablish a connection with the proxy server, and redirect the stablished socket directly to mobile webserver
3. I need to have several of these type of mobile web server (each with a different hostname) connected to a proxy server (ie. its domain is myproxy.com), and provides to a normal user a web site in mobileserverlist.myproxy.com with a list of links, each link will point to ie

   http://mobilewebserver1.myproxy.com

   http://mobilewebserver2.myproxy.com

   http://mobilewebserver3.myproxy.com

here the proxy server will redirect traffic to each mobile web server (all of them in private networks)

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you have for example a mobilephone as a web server. You can't get a static ip adress and even no dyndns domain. That you can't get dyndns domain is surprising. But you dont really need a proxy. You can easily set up a request script, that direct your users to the location you want.